# Role of interfaces for restricting access to a class

Tags: c#, interface, separation-of-concerns, visitor-pattern

Two classes, S and R and a message M (implemented as a class, a delegate or whatever).

**Could I satisfy the following requirements with the help of interfaces in C#? If yes, how?**

1. any object of S shall be able to send M to any object of R
2. any object of any other class X shall **not** be able to send M to any object of R
3. objects of S shall **not** be able to send any other message N to objects of R (although R might receive other message types from other classes' objects)
4. any attempt to send M or N in violation of the above shall result in a compiler error (ie. shall be statically checked)

It sounds quite simple and natural to me, but no matter how hard I try and search here on SO or the web, I can't find anything useful. The only thing I have found are references to the Factory pattern, which, I think, doesn't really apply here because the problem is not about construction of S,R or X.

Of course I would also be grateful for any other solution that does not involve interfaces.

**BTW**: although it sounds a little like it, this is neither a homework assignment, nor is it from a professional context. I am just a hobbyist programmer trying to explore the possibilities of the language I love.

**Edit:**

In order to provide a (hypothetical) code example: the ideal way for me would be to be able to write (pseudo-)code like below. **I know that the language does not support that**. That is the reason why I am asking to find a **pattern** or something that achieves the same thing.

```
class Receiver
{
    permits[MSender] void MessageM(); // <- I know that the "permits[]" access modifier does not exist in C#!!!
    permits[NSender] void MessageN();
}

class MSender
{
    Receiver r;
    public void JustDoIt()
    {
        r.MessageM(); // compiles successfully
        r.MessageN(); // does not compile
    }
}

class NSender // totally unrelated to sender despite the similar name
{
    Receiver r;
    public void DoItDifferently()
    {
        r.MessageM(); // does not compile
        r.MessageN(); // compiles successfully
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read about constraints with type parameters here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: @tjugg: but my classes are no generics... and the article says: "The usefulness of type parameters as constraints with generic classes is very limited because the compiler can assume nothing about the type parameter except that it derives from System.Object."

Comment: As @tjugg says make M and N interfaces and constrain (wrapped) WS to implement IM only using type constraints , (wrapped) WR implements IM and IN so another class (generic or wrapped) X that implements IN can send N type messages to WR. I dont see what the issue is. Make your question clearer with some  example code if this is not clear?

Comment: @oliver. Then wrap your classes S and R in generic wrappers with type constraints. Edited my comment above

Comment: Better to show some code to get clearer what you need

Comment: @Martino: I am afraid I don't know how to make it clearer, this is already barebones. If I post code that would already be prejudice in favor of some solution. I would not like to be critized for my naive suboptimal solutions but I want to know the state of the art.

Comment: probably you can be more specific about what is unclear. R is a receiver, S is a sender class. And I think the access rules I have laid out are self-explanatory

Comment: I am thinking of the Visitor Pattern ... R can have a method `accept( IMsender sender) { M message = sender.getMessage(); }` where S is the only implementor of IMSender. R can furthermore have other `accept` methods for different message-sender types. The above makes sure that only S can send only Ms to R and have that statically checked. Does it make sense? I have the feeling, I am missing something. (Therefor not answer, yet)

Comment: @Fildor: yeah, near the mark! I have implemented the visitor pattern way back in the past. I remember it being a little messy to maintain if more an more messages are added, at least the way I did it. And: it is dynamically type checked (ie. if a sender/receiver pair does not provide the message, you won't notice at compile time. I was hoping C# provided some more "declarative" approach, ie. with static type-checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An outline of a visitor pattern:

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/MfGWqw

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        R recv = new R();
        new S().send( recv, new M()); // OK
        new S().send( recv, new N()); // Compilation error (line 9, col 3): 
                                      // The best overloaded method match for 'S.send(R, M)' 
                                      // has some invalid arguments
        new X().send( recv, new N()); // OK
        new X().send( recv, new M()); // Also compilation error ... 
    }


}

// Message types    

public class M{}

public class N{}

// Receiver     
public class R
{
    public void accept( S sender, M message){}
    public void accept( X sender, N message){}
}

// Sender types    

public class S
{
    public void send( R receiver, M message )
    {
        receiver.accept(this, message);
    }
}

public class X
{
    public void send( R receiver, N message )
    {
        receiver.accept(this, message);
    }
}
```

I didn't use interfaces in that example, but of course, you *could*. I just wanted to outline the pattern which satisfies your requirements. I am expecting that you will need to adapt it to your needs.

EDIT: To answer your comment ...
If you are afraid of malicious implementations in S, you could address that with [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)s. An example:

```
public interface IMReceiver
{
    void accept( S sender, M message);
}
```

then change `R` :

```
public class R : IMReceiver
{
    void IMReceiver.accept( S sender, M message){} // <= explicit interface implementation.
                                                   // only visible when the reference is of 
                                                   // that interface type.
    public void accept( X sender, N message){} // you would do the same for N ...
}
```

and `S`:

```
public class S
{
    public void send( IMReceiver receiver, M message )
    {
        // receiver now has only accept( S, M ) available.
        receiver.accept(this, message);
        // MALICIOUS vv
        receiver.accept(new X(), new N()); // compilation error
    }
}
```

I only did it for S and M here for the example, but you'd probably want to do the same for X and N.

see https://dotnetfiddle.net/b14BOc

Comment: That satisfies the static type checking part in Main somehow. But I am worried about the fact that both overloads of R.accept() are public. If S wants to maliciously enforce sending a message N to R, it just has to call R.accept directly with his own messageN and a dummyX object. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Hmm, there may be a way using [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)s ...

Comment: Is that similar to Martino's answer (I still haven't grasped it, I am afraid...)?

Comment: Without looking too deeply into it, no. I'll try to mix an example in ...

Comment: The reason why I am insisting so much on these strict access restrictions is that so often it happens to me that I initially intend to call a method (or message) only from a specific class. But as the project becomes bigger (and time goes by/memory fades) I am always tempted to call the method from other places/classes. It would simply be helpful if syntactic limitations supported my original design intent instead of requiring me to remember what I did **not** want to do.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that construct. So does this mean, accept can be called on IMReceiver, but not on R? How does this play together with inheritance rules?

Comment: I linked the MS article describing the explicit interface implementation. I suggest you read it. It probably will explain much better than I ever could. "So does this mean, accept can be called on IMReceiver, but not on R?" - Yes. If you have an R, you'll need to explictly cast it to IMReceiver.

Comment: You're the man! Thank you so much! This is **exactly** what I needed to know. Let me just call it the work of a genius. :-) I will select yours as the accepted solution. For completeness I will also post an answer with fully working code that adheres to my naming in the question. I will also remove the message parameter because it is optional and was not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well I commented already about this, not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can restrict type parameters by using generics. This checks compile time.

```
public interface IOtherInterface
{

}

public interface IAnInterface<T> where T : IOtherInterface
{
    void DoSomething(T parameter);
}

public class ThisWontWork
{

}

var other = new OtherInterface();

var an = new AnInterface();

an.DoSomething(other); // this works

var wontWork = new ThisWontWork();

an.DoSomething(wontWork);  // will not build
```

Left out the classes for the interfaces but I guess you get the idea.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: hm, I think I don't know how to apply that (yet). "an" is the receiver (in my case of type R), "DoSomething" is the Message (in my case of type M), but then "other" is just a message parameter, isn't it? Maybe I am thinking too oldschool...?

Answer (score 1):

Following on from my comment, wrap your non-generic classes S and R and then apply type constraints to those wrapped classes.

UPDATE: Working code. No generics or wrapped classes actually needed. Just implementing interfaces

```
using System;

public interface IM
{
    void SendM(IRM target, string message);
}

public interface IN
{
    void SendN(IRN target, string message);
}

public interface IRM
{
    string ReceiveM(IM source, string message);
}

public interface IRN
{
    string ReceiveN(IN source, string message);
}

public class S : IM
{
     public void SendM(IRM target, string message) => target.ReceiveM(this, message);
     // Argument 1 cannot convert from S to X :-
     public void SendN(IRN target, string message) => target.ReceiveN(this, message);     }

public class X : IN
{
    public void SendN(IRN target, string message) => target.ReceiveN(this, message);
    // Argument 1 cannot convert from X to S :- 
    public void SendM(IRM target, string message) => target.ReceiveM(this, message);     }

public class Receiver : IRN, IRM
{
    public string ReceiveM(IM source, string message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ReceiveN(IN source, string message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var r = new Receiver();
        var s = new S();
        s.SendM(r, "message via M");
        var x = new X();
        x.SendN(r, "message via N");
       // s.SendN(r,"does not compile nor in intellisense");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still thinking about it... :-) I will try to edit my OP to give you something more concrete...

Comment: Thanks for the effort of applying your concept to my example. But how and where do ReceiveM and ReceiveN get called then? They are private... or do you mean they should be public?

Comment: That was just shorthand. Unless I see your code to see if your are using subscribable events or RX or Task Async etc., that is up to you and this would work wit whatever you have. Show me the code or a skeleton and I can be more specific.

Comment: The point is that if Receiver.Receive*() are public, somebody may be tempted to circumvent the whole mechanism by directly calling them. Sorry if that didn't come out of my question so clearly.

Comment: Added working code. This is about using interfaces to prevent  nongeneric Sender from using N. This code does this.  (In fact you don't need generics for this just implementing interfaces as this code shows) As for the issues over public and so on you never showed your code to see what you other issues are. That would be another question I think.

Comment: Added source constraint into Receive*() methods. Anyway need to see what your message mechanism is as I asked before events or what?

Comment: yes true, originally I had no code. But now it's in the question already for some time. Actually I had no prejudice in favor of any message mechanism, as long as the requirements are satisfied.

Comment: But if you want to see more code, you could also take a look at my (i.e. actually Fildor's) answer below.

Answer (score 1):

By courtesy of Fildor's (accepted) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047377/2118609) - which is basically **a visitor pattern plus additional access restrictions on the Receiver side through explicit interface implementation** - I have also prepared a fully working example that illustrates it.

The only way to abuse (i.e. a send message from prohibited sender) a newly created Receiver is via explicit cast to one of the Interfaces in connection with the creation of the respective dummy Sender object. As a safety risk I consider this acceptable because it is hard to bypass by accident.

```
public interface IMReceiver
{
    void MessageM(MSender sender);
}

public interface INReceiver
{
    void MessageN(NSender sender);
}

public class Receiver: IMReceiver, INReceiver
{
    string name;
    public Receiver(string newName) {name = newName;}

    void IMReceiver.MessageM(MSender sender) {Console.WriteLine(name+" received Message M from "+sender.Name);}
    void INReceiver.MessageN(NSender sender) {Console.WriteLine(name+" received Message N from "+sender.Name);}
}

public class MSender
{
    void sendMessageMTo(IMReceiver r) {r.MessageM(this);}

    public readonly string Name = "an MSender";
    Receiver r1 = new Receiver("Alice");
    Receiver r2 = new Receiver("Bob");

    public void JustDoIt()
    {
        sendMessageMTo(r1);
        sendMessageMTo(r2);

        // thinkable abuses:

        // sendMessageNTo(r1); // is simply not defined
        // r1.MessageN(this); // does not compile without cast
        // (r1 as INReceiver).MessageN(this); // does not compile with this Sender type
        (r1 as INReceiver).MessageN(new NSender()); // possible, but unlikely to happen by accident
    }
}

public class NSender
{
    void sendMessageNTo(INReceiver r) {r.MessageN(this);}

    public readonly string Name = "an NSender";
    Receiver r3 = new Receiver("Clive");
    Receiver r4 = new Receiver("Dan");

    public void DoItDifferently()
    {
        sendMessageNTo(r3);
        sendMessageNTo(r4);
    }
}
```

and in Main:

```
MSender ms = new MSender();
NSender ns = new NSender();

ms.JustDoIt();
ns.DoItDifferently();
```